# Convert `defaultdict` string object in pandas dataframe to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a string representation of dictionary in pandas dataframe column. I need to extract the dict.

Here's my minimal reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({
                'id': ['7e9zsX7CM4','ftisjah421'], 
                'img_dict': ["defaultdict(< class 'list'>, {'7e9zsX7CM4': ['https://image_1.png','https://image_2.png']})", "  "] 
             })

img_dict = df['img_dict'][0]

print(type(img_dict))

<class 'str'>
```

Note, there are some `NaNs` in `df['img_dict']` column and applying `ast.literal_eval` returns

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: nan
```

This is how data was presented in pandas dataframe. So, I am trying to find hacky ways to convert this string to a python dictionary? In an ideal world, this object should have been stored as `dict` and not `string`, however, I don't own the data.

Comment: @Corralien posting new question

Comment: I voted to close the question last time because answering properly requires information about the problem that isn't being provided: specifically, *why the data looks like this and why the problem needs to be solved*. If you "don't own the data", the fix is to *contact the person who owns the data and file a bug report with the code*. Outputting in this format **is broken**.

Comment: It's also unclear what result is actually needed: is a new instance of `defaultdict` required, or would an ordinary `dict` work? It's also unclear why the data is being loaded into a Dataframe; it's suggestive of improperly stored JSON.

Comment: I am voting to close again because the problem with the question hasn't been addressed.

Comment: Please read https://xyproblem.info/ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is a hack. It can't be a satisfied solution but it should work for your case. It will be better if your column `img_dict` was a JSON object.

You have to extract the second argument of the `defaultdict` representation (`repr`) and use `literal_eval` from `ast` module to (try to) recreate the dict (not the defaultdict).

```
default_dict(default_factory, dict)
```

```
import ast

df['dict'] = \
    df.loc[df['img_dict'].str.startswith('defaultdict', na=False), 'img_dict'] \
      .str.extract('({.*})', expand=False) \
      .apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

```
>>> df
           id                                           img_dict                                               dict
0  7e9zsX7CM4  defaultdict(< class 'list'>, {'7e9zsX7CM4': ['...  {'7e9zsX7CM4': ['https://image_1.png', 'https:...
1  ftisjah421                                                                                                   NaN

>>> df.iloc[0, 2]
{'7e9zsX7CM4': ['https://image_1.png', 'https://image_2.png']}

>>> type(df.iloc[0, 2])
dict
```

Comment: I get this error: `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`

Comment: Adding `na=False` flag seems to be the fix.